# How do you connect the edge so the end of it is connected to the specific vertex below?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, vertex-groups

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

How do I make it that so that line in the middle(which is coming from yellow to orange) is connected to the orange dot. Not to the dot above like it is connected on the picture.

Comment: Can you please add a blend file

Comment: Perhaps you want to select one vertex, than another, right-click, *Merge Vertices* -> *at last*?

Comment: Please add more detail, some extra images with the lines and vertices you are referring to circled in different colours. It's hard to know what edges you are talking about as there are so many. But to take a guess, you probably want to create a custom transform orientation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I changed the picture above. I basically want line in the middle (from which yellow line is coming) to be connected to the orange dot, not the dot above which it's already connected to.